RAID 5 array won't assemble, lsblk shows drive size as 115.5P for all drives in array
I have a raid-5 array comprised of 4 2TB drives that has been operational since 2018. One day I noticed that access was very slow, and the next day it was completely inaccessible. I have an old (2011) HP Z800 workstation running xcp-ng, and the 4 drives are in a NAS box connected via USB.  The server is running in an out of the way place and nobody bumped it or anything like that.  I had the 4 disks attached to a VM running ClearOS which was exposing it as a network file store.
ClearOS services became inaccessible, and that did not change with a reboot. Commenting out the fstab entry for the raid array was the only way to bring ClearOS back up to a fully functional state, sans file store.
At this point, if I attach the disks to the VM, the VM won't start.  I created a new RHEL 9 VM and attached the disks to it, and that VM wouldn't start either.  I can attach the disks after the VM has started.  After attaching the disks to the running ClearOS instance, I see errors like these from dmesg:
[  489.596733] blkfront: xvdb: barrier: enabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: disabled;
[  489.599044] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 0
[  489.599081] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdb, logical block 0, async page read
[  489.599112] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 2
[  489.599131] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdb, logical block 1, async page read
[  489.599155] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 4
[  489.599174] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdb, logical block 2, async page read
[  489.599197] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 6
[  489.599215] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdb, logical block 3, async page read
[  489.599294] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 0
[  489.599315] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdb, logical block 0, async page read
[  489.599340] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 2
[  489.599359] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdb, logical block 1, async page read
[  489.599382] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 4
[  489.599401] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdb, logical block 2, async page read
[  489.599448] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 6
[  489.599468] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdb, logical block 3, async page read
[  489.599541] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 0
[  489.599563] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdb, logical block 0, async page read
[  489.599588] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 2
[  489.599607] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdb, logical block 1, async page read
[  489.599954] Dev xvdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[  489.600116]  xvdb: unable to read partition table
[  516.312816] blkfront: xvdc: barrier: enabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: disabled;
[  516.315148] blk_update_request: 31 callbacks suppressed
[  516.315151] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 0
[  516.315178] buffer_io_error: 30 callbacks suppressed
[  516.315180] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdc, logical block 0, async page read
[  516.315207] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 2
[  516.315226] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdc, logical block 1, async page read
[  516.315253] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 4
[  516.315272] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdc, logical block 2, async page read
[  516.315299] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 6
[  516.315318] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdc, logical block 3, async page read
[  516.315464] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 0
[  516.315492] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdc, logical block 0, async page read
[  516.315530] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 2
[  516.315559] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdc, logical block 1, async page read
[  516.315585] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 4
[  516.315604] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdc, logical block 2, async page read
[  516.315633] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 6
[  516.315663] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdc, logical block 3, async page read
[  516.315783] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 0
[  516.315809] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdc, logical block 0, async page read
[  516.315847] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 2
[  516.315874] Buffer I/O error on dev xvdc, logical block 1, async page read
[  516.316395] Dev xvdc: unable to read RDB block 0
[  516.316585]  xvdc: unable to read partition table
[  527.385824] blkfront: xvde: barrier: enabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: disabled;
[  538.187957] blk_update_request: 31 callbacks suppressed
[  538.187994] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 0
[  538.188036] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 88
[  538.188059] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 176
[  538.188241] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 0
[  538.188319] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 88
[  538.188360] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 176
[  538.188874] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 0
[  538.188950] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 88
[  538.188986] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdb, sector 176
[  538.190106] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev xvdc, sector 0
[  557.731002] blkfront: xvdf: barrier: enabled; persistent grants: disabled; indirect descriptors: disabled;

Running mdadm --assemble --scan -v takes a very long time and it results in the following:
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/xvdf
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/xvde
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/xvdc
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/xvdb
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/dm-1
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/dm-0
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sr0: No medium found
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/xvda2
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/xvda1
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/xvda
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically


lsblk output:
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0               11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
xvda             202:0    0   100G  0 disk
├─xvda1          202:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─xvda2          202:2    0    99G  0 part
  ├─clearos-root 253:0    0  93.1G  0 lvm  /
  └─clearos-swap 253:1    0   5.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
xvdb             202:16   0 115.5P  0 disk
xvdc             202:32   0 115.5P  0 disk
xvde             202:64   0 115.5P  0 disk
xvdf             202:80   0 115.5P  0 disk


Note that the drive size for each drive is 115.5P!  Don't I wish...
If I try to force assembly, I get this:
# mdadm --assemble -v /dev/md127 /dev/xvd[bcef]
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md127
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/xvdb
mdadm: /dev/xvdb has no superblock - assembly aborted

Restoring the fstab entry and trying mount -a. After a long while:
mount: can't find UUID=5caefb50-21b8-4c33-b502-bdfa8554736a

I thought of using badblocks to scan the drives, but the 115.5P prevents that as there are (supposedly) way to many blocks.
badblocks: Value too large for defined data type invalid end block (31734923844828): must be 32-bit value

Running smartctl on the vm gives the following error:
# smartctl --all /dev/xvdc
smartctl 7.0 2018-12-30 r4883 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-1160.71.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-18, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/xvdc: Unable to detect device type
Please specify device type with the -d option.

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary


But if I run it on dom0 then it runs properly for all 4 drives and reports no issues.  It also reports the correct 2TB for each drive.  If I try to assemble the array on dom0, I get the same error as I did in the VM.
smartctl --all /dev/sdf
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0+1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4M7XJ8JV9
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2ba91ca6f
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jul  2 19:55:15 2024 CDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (27900) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 282) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x703d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   184   174   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3791
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       165
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   031   031   000    Old_age   Always       -       50782
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       74
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       61
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       6712
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   113   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.


# smartctl --all /dev/sdg
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0+1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4M3TF7917
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 20ffb6850
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jul  2 19:58:26 2024 CDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (27720) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 280) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x703d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   177   170   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4133
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       165
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   031   031   000    Old_age   Always       -       50781
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       74
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       61
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       6797
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   113   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.


# smartctl --all /dev/sdh
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0+1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4M2ZCSA19
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2ba91c75c
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jul  2 19:58:48 2024 CDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (28380) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 286) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x703d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   176   170   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4183
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       165
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   031   031   000    Old_age   Always       -       50781
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       74
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       61
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       6736
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   112   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.


# smartctl --all /dev/sdi
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0+1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4M1XK9T0D
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2653b8962
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jul  2 19:59:04 2024 CDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (28020) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 283) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x703d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   190   172   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3491
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       164
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   031   031   000    Old_age   Always       -       50776
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       74
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       62
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       6834
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   110   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       37
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.


So where do I go from here?  Anybody have any suggestions?

I assume dom0 is a a bare metal system. Assuming the drive is just 'data' - and that's the case I wonder if backing up and rebuilding the array entirely from scratch would be an option

dom0 is the host system for a hypervisor (xcp-ng in this case). I do have the data backed up, but I would like to determine if the array can be saved as-is, or if the drives are bad, or if even the server itself is failing (it's from 2011).
